# Is Android emulator work in Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community version. Currently, I am debugging on real devices.

How can I debug the project on emulators?

Comment: Have you actually **tried** running it? What issues did you encounter?

Comment: My system is windows 10 home, pro/enterprise edition is needed to run Microsoft visual studio emulator. right?

Comment: Where did you find that information?

Comment: when I run the visual studio set up I got that information

Comment: Then your issue is not VS Community, but Windows 10 Home!?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found on Windows 10 fall creator's update that I need to use the HAXM version which can easily be installed from Android Studio's SDK manager (not the stand-alone Android SDK manager).  After you have run an emulator from Android Studio it will appear in the VS2017 dropdown as an option from then on.  No emulators have been started if you only see the `Live Player` option.  The Hyper-V Android emulator does not seem to be working on Windows 10 winver `1709`.